# Automatically capture image after focusing Cordova camera-preview

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins

I'm new to ionic and I'm trying to do the following:

1. create a finger structure overlay on the image before capture.
2. capture an image automatically after focusing on the object (finger) which is within the overlay and alert if the object is far or very close to the camera.

I managed only to startCamera and takePicture on a button click

here are my page.ts codes:

```
export class SignupCustomerWithoutDocumentsPage implements OnInit {

    data = {
        fingerprintBase64: '',
    };

    constructor(
        public utility: UtilityProvider,
        private cameraPreview: CameraPreview,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {}

    async openCamera() {
        const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
            x: 0,
            y: (window.screen.height - (window.screen.width * 2 / 3) - 200),
            width: window.screen.width,
            height: (window.screen.width * 2 / 3),
            camera: 'rear',
            tapPhoto: false,
            tapFocus: false,
            previewDrag: false,
            toBack: false,
            alpha: 1,
        }

        await this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts);
        this.cameraPreview.setFlashMode("torch");
        this.cameraPreview.setFocusMode("continuous-picture")
    }

    takephoto() {
        const pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
            quality: 25
        }

        // take a picture
        this.cameraPreview.takePicture(pictureOpts).then((imageData) => {
            this.data.fingerprintBase64 = imageData;
            this.cameraPreview.stopCamera();
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.utility.presentAlert('failed')
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question? How to compare two images (image overlay and camera preview)?

Comment: the overlay is to instruct user where to place fingers. The aim is to extract fingerprints from the image captured by user and send it to third part